# Returning a string from an IEnumerable<T>function

Tags: c#, algorithm, ienumerable

I am probably doing something wrong but I'm trying to do [this Kata on Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54e6533c92449cc251001667/train/csharp)

This is my current code below.

```
public static class Kata
{
 public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> arr) 
 {
   Type t = typeof(T);
   if (t == typeof(string))
     return (IEnumerable<T>)String.Join("",arr.Distinct()).AsEnumerable();
   
   return arr.Distinct().ToArray();
 }
}
```

The unit tests for this kata are expecting an input of "AAAABBBCCDAABBB" to be returned as "ABCDAB".

My code above is failing due to this error
`Expected is <System.String>, actual is <System.Char[6]>`

If I try to return a string I get this error: `error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'`

I'm lost as how I can return the expected string if I can't return a string (and a char array fails)

Thanks

Comment: You pass a `string` which is an `IEnumerable<char>` not an `IEnumerable<string>` which means `T` is `char` and not `string` so your `if (t == typeof(string))` returns `false`.

Comment: Note that you cannot simply solve this problem with a call to `.Distinct()`; if that was the case there'd be no challenge in it.

Comment: Your return type is `IEnumerable<T>`, but you assert it as `string`.

Comment: Also... there's no reason to call `ToArray()` the end. It just wastes memory and cpu. The `Distinct()` method on it's own already fulfills your IEnumerable contract. If the caller actually wants an array (or list, or whatever), let them make that choice.

Comment: Do it the old fashioned way.  Loop through the IEnumerable, if element `i` is the same as element `i-1` throw it away.  If not, `yield return` it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement it like this (since you've used `<T>` let implement *general case* solution with custom `comparer`):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                              IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

  comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

  bool first = true;
  T prior = default; // default: let compiler be happy

  foreach (T item in source)
    if (first || !comparer.Equals(item, prior)) {
      prior = item;
      first = false;

      yield return item;
    }
}
```

Here we just check if current `item` is equal to `prior`.

**Demo:**

```
string source = "AAAABBBCCDAABBB";

string result = string.Concat(UniqueInOrder(source)); 

Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
ABCDAB
```

**Edit:** Please, note that `Distinct()` in the

```
arr.Distinct()
```

removes duplicates in the *entire* `arr`, that's why you'll get only 4 distinct characters:

```
AAAABBBCCDAABBB  ->  ABCD
             Distinct()
```

In the given problem we have a *weaker* condition: current item must not be equal to prior.

Comment: Nice! I was just banging my head on their test: `Expected is <System.String>, actual is <System.Linq.Enumerable+DistinctIterator`1[System.Char]>` So let's teach beginners the wonderful use of `Distinct` and then jump through amazing hoops to get the return type right to satisfy the test. Why would they hand a string into a method like this. This doesn't happen in the real world... unless you're using Java. (I use java, not insighting a flame war. :P)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) 
{
    using var e = iterable.GetEnumerator();
    bool EnumeratorActive = e.MoveNext(); //start iterating
    while (EnumeratorActive)
    {
        // set and yield the current value
        T cur = e.Current; 
        yield return cur;

        // keep advancing while the iterator is active and additional values match the current val
        while(cur.Equals(e.Current) && (EnumeratorActive = e.MoveNext()))
        {} //empty body intentional
    }    
}
```

It uses a pattern of nested while loops called **Control/Break** that still runs in linear time (because only the inner loop advances).

Here's a reduced version without the extra explainers:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) 
{
    using var e = iterable.GetEnumerator();
    bool EnumeratorActive = e.MoveNext();
    while (EnumeratorActive)
    {
        T cur = e.Current; 
        yield return cur;
        while(cur.Equals(e.Current) && (EnumeratorActive = e.MoveNext()));
    }    
}
```

Comment: This fails if the sequence contains elements that are `null` (which, presumably, is allowed; at least there's no reason to assume it's not). If you're not going to use `EqualityComparer`, you may as well use the static `Object.Equals`.